# gradient color of body in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, gradient, background-color

I have a question about gradient in react js. when I use a gradient color it's not look like work correctly.

can someone explain to me why this is hapenning?

when I use a gradient color for my body this happening:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIEDy.png)
and it's my code:

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #baac39, #e78521, #ff444b, #ff0092, #c512eb);
}
```

I try it with a lot of gradient code but always this is happening. but when i add a "height" it's work correct and show me this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAiYV.png)
it's my new code :

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #baac39, #e78521, #ff444b, #ff0092, #c512eb);
  height: 1000px;
}
```

why this happening?

and it's correct i use "height" for fix it?

Comment: if i get to the html 100% height it's work too.  (html { height : 100%; } ) and then delete a height of body. but i still don't know why it's look like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: when i use this code before my gradient color, i dont have a color  whole page it just top pf the page.

Comment: because you don't have any content in the `body`  element, you should put some contents inside the `body` or specify a `height` which is a bad idea.

Comment: if i have a just one element in my page it's look like bad. sometimes we don't have a lot of element in the one page.

Comment: You can use `min-height: 100vh;` on the body.